# tensorflow error code for implementation to Jetson Nano

Tags: python, nvidia-jetson-nano

why is this happening?
[Errno 2] No Such file or directory: '/home/Documents/unetarchi.json'

line 23, in 
json_file = open (jsonPath, 'r')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am currently working on a highway segmentation project for autonomous vehicle navigation. then output the desired model in order to recognize a good road trajectory. currently coding in python for implementation to Jetson Nano and there is a problem like the one in question. what is the solution? thank you